# Terraform looking for unspecified providers in 0.13

Tags: terraform

I am trying to upgrade from Terraform 0.12 to 0.13.

I added a `required_providers` block as shown below:

```
required_providers {
  gorillastack = {
    source  = "GorillaStack/gorillastack"
    version = "0.3.4"
  }
  aws = {
    source = "hashicorp/aws"
  }
}

provider "gorillastack" {
  api_key = xxx
  team_id = yyy
}
```

This block is in my module.

I then try and `terraform init` and I get this:

```
Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of -/aws...
- Finding gorillastack/gorillastack versions matching "0.3.4"...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/aws...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/gorillastack...
- Installing -/aws v3.30.0...
- Installed -/aws v3.30.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing gorillastack/gorillastack v0.3.4...
- Installed gorillastack/gorillastack v0.3.4 (self-signed, key ID C736B561C5602EFE)
- Installing hashicorp/aws v3.30.0...
- Installed hashicorp/aws v3.30.0 (signed by HashiCorp)

Partner and community providers are signed by their developers.
If you'd like to know more about provider signing, you can read about it here:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/plugins/signing.html

Error: Failed to install provider

Error while installing hashicorp/gorillastack: provider registry
registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/gorillastack
```

So it looks like Terraform correctly reads my required_providers block and tries to install 'gorillastack/gorillastack' and 'hashicorp/aws'.

But it also wants to try and install '-/aws' and 'hashicorp/gorillastack'.

I read this may happen if your resource names are not prefixed with the provider name. But in my case all my resources start 'gorillastack_'

'-aws' it seems to find I assume because this is a hashicorp official provider but it fails to find 'hashicorp/gorillastack' and the init fails.

So my question is why is Terraform trying to download hashicorp/gorillastack when I have defined gorillastack in my `required_providers` block and prefixed all my resources with 'gorillastack_'?

Comment: Thanks for the details of the issue in my case it was the issue like this:
`I read this may happen if your resource names are not prefixed with the provider name. But in my case all my resources start 'gorillastack_'`
I updated my resource name in schema and got fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform v0.13 has introduced the idea of there being a hierarchical namespace for providers.

The providers in the "hashicorp" namespace (like `hashicorp/aws` here) are ones where folks at HashiCorp either primarily maintain or contribute heavily to them. Other namespaces, like `gorillastack` here, contain providers that are maintained either by HashiCorp partners or by others in the community who don't have any specific relationship with HashiCorp.

For backward compatibility with as many modules written for Terraform v0.12 as possible, Terraform automatically assumes that any provider not specifically declared is intended to belong to the `hashicorp` namespace. However, the modern way to write a Terraform module is to add a `required_providers` block as you've shown in your question, which specifies which providers each module depends on and what local name (`aws` and `gorillastack` in your example here) you'll use to refer to that provider elsewhere in that same module, such as in `provider "gorillastack"` blocks where there is no explicit namespace given.

I think the problem in your case is that you've added a `required_providers` block to your root module but not to at least one other module in your configuration, and so Terraform's fallback behavior is assuming that the module is intending to use a provider called `hashicorp/gorillastack`.

You can use the `terraform providers` command to see which providers each of your modules depends on. Look for each one that includes a dependency on `hashicorp/gorillastack` and then edit its source code to include a `required_providers` block just like the one you showed in your question above.

The other special thing happening in the example you showed is that Terraform is using a special "legacy" provider address `-/aws` to represent a provider that your previous state snapshot was referring to, which Terraform doesn't yet (at `terraform init` time) know how to map to a namespaced provider. Once you deal with the problem with the `gorillastack/gorillastack` provider you should see `terraform init` succeed and install a temporary plugin for `-/aws` just to deal with a one-time state migration that will happen the first time you let `terraform apply` run successfully to completion. After that, you should no longer have any `-/aws` references in your state snapshot and so `terraform init` will no longer install that temporary migration provider.

Comment: Thanks @martin

"I think the problem in your case is that you've added a required_providers block to your root module but not to at least one other module in your configuration"

 - this exactly.  I had defined the required_providers block in the root module but not the module it was calling.  Once I had defined the required_providers block in both modules then everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
provider "gorillastack" {
  api_key = "${var.api_key}"
  team_id = "${var.team_id}"
}
```

From their docs:
https://github.com/GorillaStack/terraform-provider-gorillastack

Comment: api_key and team_id were obfuscated for the purposes of the post.  I don't feel it would have a bearing on the installation of providers.

Comment: Hmm you're right. I see they have a slack. Gonna try build it locally and see if that works. My bad.

Comment: I get an error when I try build the provider with go locally. I'd say ditch this provider for now if you can otherwise try hop on their slack.